# What does aws lambda use to run scheduled task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, automation, cron

I am trying to understand the implementation of AWS lambda scheduling.

Suppose I created a function and schedule it for some future time.

Then does AWS is running some cron jobs every minute or second to check all the scheduled tasks and run them if match?

Or they are using some different method?

Basically, I want to implement a similar functionality where the user can schedule a task and my system then complete it at a scheduled time.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: It uses CloudWatch events https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html

Comment: Then question remains the same, what does cloudwatch use to trigger schedule task? Is it running a cron job every minute to check all the schedule job in the account/region and then trigger it. I updated the question

Comment: Per your update, use a job scheduler for your language. Eg Celery if your app is python, sidekiq for ruby, quartz for java, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I did know about message queue but it didn't know about task queue. I am using nodejs and there are bull and other lib.  Many thanks!